# Unordered list is uneven with css property/value columns: 4 on safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I added the breaks to the li because safari was splitting the location from the name when splitting the columns. After adding that the columns don't appear top aligned. The second and fourth column are lower compared to the first and third column. Any ideas why? Screenshot example here:
[image]

```
.team-responsive-col ul{
    columns: 4;
    margin-left:0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.team-responsive-col ul li{
    margin-bottom:30px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
          page-break-inside: avoid;
               break-inside: avoid;
}

<div class="team-responsive-col">
<ul>
<li><strong>Name 1</strong><br />
<em>Location</em></li>
<li><strong>Name 1<br />
</strong><em>Location</em></li>
<li><strong>Name 1<br />
</strong><em>Location</em></li>
<li><strong>Name 1<br />
</strong><em>Location</em></li>
<li><strong>Name 1<br />
</strong><em>Location</em></li>
<li><strong>Name 1<br />
</strong><em>Location</em></li>
<li><strong>Name 1<br />
</strong><em>Location</em></li>
<li><strong>Name 1<br />
</strong><em>Location</em></li>
<li><strong>Name 1<br />
</strong><em>Location</em></li>
<li><strong>Name 1<br />
</strong><em>Location</em></li>
<li><strong>Name 1<br />
</strong><em>Location</em></li>
<li><strong>Name 1<br />
</strong><em>Location</em></li>
<li><strong>Name 1<br />
</strong><em>Location</em></li>
<li><strong>Name 1<br />
</strong><em>Location</em></li>
<li><strong>Name 1<br />
</strong><em>Location</em></li>
<li><strong>Name 1<br />
</strong><em>Location</em></li>
<li><strong>Name 1<br />
</strong><em>Location</em></li>
<li><strong>Name 1<br />
</strong><em>Location</em></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted is exactly what you have in your original? Because the jagged tops only appear when I move the `break-inside` from `.team-responsive-col ul li {...}` to `.team-responsive-col ul {...}`. The posted code works fine on W10 Edge, IE11, Chrome and Firefox without misalignments...

Comment: The only browser that's having an issue is safari. The code is as I have it above on the website.

Comment: Sorry to say, can't help you any further as I'm on W10. Maybe only use `-webkit-column-break-inside` in `.team-responsive-col ul li` to test if it has something to do with the order of the page-break properties in the CSS. Beyond that...?

Comment: Appreciate the responses! Aparently I just needed to sleep on it. Removing the margin-bottom but adding space as padding worked better: .page-id-4888 .team-responsive-col ul li {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

Comment: Still surprises me that Safari has an issue with that. Having said that, in the box-model `margin` is not considered to be a part of the element (in either `content-box` or `border-box` mode). If not already, do make sure you understand the difference: while `content-box` is HTML default, `border-box` is the preferred mode by most developers. [w3Schools: CSS box-sizing Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp), bookmark this site, great for reference!